# Can not open and use cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

Everytime I try to open Cmd, it just appear and close immediately. Even when I use terminal in VS Code. So I can use commands such as node, npm and composer. I still can open PowerShell but I can't run any commands.
Can anyone help me solve this problem!
Thank you!!!

Comment: What happens when you use one or more appropriate options? e.g. `"%__AppDir__%cmd.exe" /D /K`

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying the AutoRun RegKey found here "Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor" in the registry.